# Can't access array index in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, axios

I'm trying to access an array of arrays in javascript but always getting undefined.
Here is my code:

```
const Servers = [{
    "ID": 1,
    "IP": "192.168.1.11",
    "Enabled": true,
  },
  {
    "ID": 2,
    "IP": "192.168.1.12",
    "Enabled": true,
  }
]

const channels = []

const loadChannels = () => {
  Servers.map((server, key) => {
    if (server.Enabled == true) {
      axios.get(server.IP).then((response) => {
        if (response.data.response >= 400) {
          console.log(response)
        } else {
          channels.push(response.data.data)
          console.log(key, response.data.data) // 
        }
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
      })
    }
  })
}

loadChannels()

console.log('channels', channels)

console.log('index 0 :', channels[0])
```

and here is the console output

[image: console output]

What am I doing wrong? Can anybody help me please.
Many thanks!

Comment: is `channels.push = (response.data.data)`  typo or

Comment: It is typo, should be “‘ channels.push(response.data.data)”’

Comment: Note: `if (expr == true)` is the same as `if (expr)`.